# Consitent date, numbers formatting across C# (backend) and JS (front end)

Tags: javascript, c#, globalization, javascript-globalize, jquery-globalize

I am writing a system which shows customer data in front-end, but also allows exporting data via back-end to various file formats. I am using globalize.js and .NET's native Globalization capabilities, but for some languages I am getting  differences in date format (eg. "31.1.2016" vs. "31-01-2016") and number format (eg. "1.234,56" vs "1 234,56"). Does anybody have any suggestion how can format dates and numbers across back-end and front-end and still get consistent results?

I can't pre-format values to string and pass strings to the front-end, because some front-end components (like charts) expect raw integers, dates to to be able to render the data properly.

Comment: You said; _how can format dates and numbers_ and also _I can't format values to string_. How do you think you can format them _without_ formatting? o.O I'm confused.

Comment: I was about to write the very same. This question makes no sense... you have a problem with formatting but you are not formatting?

Comment: He means he can't pass pre-formatted string to the front-end

Comment: Yes, Cecilio Pardo is right

Comment: Please, which Globalize.js version are you using and which locales are you referring to in your example?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass from the back-end both things: The numerical date and the string representation.